# SQL TRANSACTION Left join result in null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a problem where I insert User and Address in a transaction with a 10 second delay and if run my select statement during the execution of the transaction it will wait for transaction to finish but I will get a null on the join. Why don't my select wait for both User/Address data to be committed.
If I run the select statement after the transaction is finish I will get the correct result. Why do i get this error and what is the generic solution to make this work

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION   
 insert into user(dummy) values('text')
 WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';
 insert into address(ID_FK) values((SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()))
COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

Running during transaction result in null in join

```
select * from user u left join address a on u.id = a.ID_FK order by id desc
```

```
| ID | dummy | ID_FK | 
| 101 | 'text' | null |
```

Running after transaction result in correct result

```
select * from user u left join address a on u.id = a.ID_FK order by id desc
```

```
| ID | dummy |  ID_FK|
| 101 | 'text' | 101 |
```

[image]

Comment: I don't follow what you're asking here. Of course if you try to query the table outside of the transaction *before* that transaction has been committed, you aren't going to see the row; it's not committed. Only within the transaction will you get that row.

Comment: What is your isolation level for the select query? It's not seeing the second row regardless  because you wait 10 seconds before inserting it, so it's not there.

Comment: Well that's the weird thing i looks like i get the result from user but not from address.

Comment: Also `insert into user` is going to error. `USER` is a reserved keyword.

Comment: Can you add the whole query that you are running during the transaction in which you are getting null??

Comment: I don't see the problem here: the behaviour is as expected: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=68492d1fc3cde2879125cb77f18ccab5)

Comment: I think the OP means (it's not clear) his `select` is running in a separate connection at the same time as the insert...?

Comment: yes the are running in separate connections

Comment: In which case your `select` must be running as `read uncommited`, issue  `set transaction isolation level read committed` and retry.

Comment: Added a PrtScn not that the tables are named test1/test2 in the prtScn rest is the same

Comment: I tried set transaction isolation level read committed but got the same result

Comment: @Stu - that is not the case. I give an example scenario where this can happen in my answer

Comment: @MartinSmith Thanks for the example, that's interesting - so it honours the lock as you'd expect, it's more of a 'timing' issue by continuing with part of the query while the other part is waiting, is that right?

Comment: yeah, at no point does it read uncommitted data - but it reads `address` before the open transaction has even done anything to it and reads the row from `user` after the open transaction has committed and the row lock is released.

Answer (score 1):

This type of thing is entirely possible at default read committed level for on premise SQL Server as that uses read committed locking. It is then execution plan dependent what will happen.

An example is below

```
CREATE TABLE [user]
  (
     id    INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
     dummy VARCHAR(10)
  );

CREATE TABLE [address]
  (
     ID_FK INT REFERENCES [user](id),
     addr  VARCHAR(30)
  );
```

**Connection One**

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

INSERT INTO [user]
            (dummy)
VALUES     ('text')

WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:20';

INSERT INTO address
            (ID_FK,
             addr)
VALUES     (SCOPE_IDENTITY(),
            'Address Line 1')

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

**Connection Two (run this whilst connection one is waiting the 20 seconds)**

```
SELECT *
FROM   [user] u
       LEFT JOIN [address] a
              ON u.id = a.ID_FK
ORDER  BY id DESC
OPTION (MERGE JOIN)
```

Returns

| id | dummy | ID_FK | addr |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | text | NULL | NULL |

The execution plan is as follows

[image]

The scan on `User` is blocked by the open transaction in Connection 1 that has inserted the row there. This has to wait until that transaction commits and then eventually gets to read the newly inserted row.

Meanwhile the Sort operator has already requested the rows from `address` by this point as it consumes all its rows in its `Open` method (i.e. during operator initialisation). This is not blocked as no row has been inserted to `address` yet. It reads 0 rows from `address` which explains the final result.

If you switch to using read committed snapshot rather than read committed locking you won't get this issue as it will only read the committed state at the start of the statement so it isn't possible to get this kind of anomaly.