# SQL solve Left join issue without Repeatable Read or TABLOCKX

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server and I insert User and Address in a transaction with a delay to simulate high load and if I run the select on UserTable and Left join with AddressTable at the same time as i execute transaction i will get null in the join with address.

I believe the SQL interpreter is eagerly fetching data from the "Address table" and will wait for UserTable data so the result will be a null in the join.

I found two solutions for this issue by.

- Setting transaction level to Repeatable Read
- Put a TABLOCKX on AddressTable.

Are there any other cleaner options for solving this issue and still use "Left join".

```
select * 
from UserTable u 
left join AddressTable a on u.id = a.ID_FK 
order by id desc

BEGIN TRANSACTION   
 -- Optional lock of AddressTable   SELECT TOP 1 ID_FK  FROM AddressTable WITH (TABLOCKX)
    INSERT INTO UserTable (data) 
    VALUES (100)

    WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10';

    INSERT INTO AddressTable (ID_FK) 
    VALUES ((SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()))

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

SQL PrtSC

[image: SQL PrtSC]

Comment: Have the reading transaction use read committed snapshot rather than read committed locking so it gets a consistent view of the data across all tables involved. You could see this type of thing if it reads AddressTable (before the row is inserted there) and then uses that as a build input to a hash join, or sorts it, before reading UserTable (by which time the row has been inserted there)

Comment: Duplicate of your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67317882/sql-transaction-left-join-result-in-null). As others have guessed and demonstrated, your problem is impossible without using nolock or similar settings.

Comment: @smor It is entirely possible for this to happen at traditional read committed level